# Why is my NPM package is not working in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel, npm, package

I created an npm package for myself, but when I tried to use it in laravel, it returns a ReferenceError.
So here is what I did:
I followed the tutorial on how to initiate an npm package, and it works how it should work in standard javascript.
So I did the following in my laravel app:

```
npm install @ilayalmalem/lingojs
```

It worked, and a folder was instantiated in the node_modules folder.

I added the following to the app.js:

```
window.lingo = require('@ilayalmalem/lingojs');
```

But when I try to use it in a blade view like this:

```
var lingo = new Lingo('.s',{
     Models:{
       model1:'d'
     }
});
```

It returns:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Lingo is not defined
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "@ilayalmalem/lingojs",
  "version": "0.0.4",
  "description": "Write less javascript.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "lingo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/ilayalmalem/Lingo.js.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "LingoJS",
    "Backend",
    "communication"
  ],
  "author": "Ilay David Almalem",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/ilayalmalem/Lingo.js/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/ilayalmalem/Lingo.js#readme"
}
```

Here is how I instantiate the Lingo class:

```
class Lingo {
...code
}
```

If you really interested in the code check this:
https://github.com/ilayalmalem/Lingo.js

If you need more information, just comment.

Comment: How about `new window.lingo()`

Comment: @dbf thank you for your answer! but I just answered it. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So guys, if you ever run to this problem, just add this line to your index.js:

```
module.exports = your class;
```

and don't forget to run:

```
node your_main_file.js
```

in the command line.